# How to find math equation in Word file and if found then highlighted it using vsto c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, mathtype

How can I find math equation in Word file?

Please suggest for the same.

My output will be getting like this:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Word? How was the math equation created? Do you need to find a specific equation or any/all equations in a document?

Comment: @Cindy, Here use office 2010 and install "MathType" then u will get equation

Comment: "MathType" is a third-party product, which I don't have. So I don't know what kind of object it puts on Word's document surface. Possibly, it's a member of the InlineShapes collection and, if there's an OLEServer in the background, you can get more information about it via the InlineShape.Object.OleFormat property. But that's just a guess on my part.. You can probably get better information from the MathType manufacturer http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/default.asp. Looking at the website, I also see a SDK is provided for the product, which might also help.

Comment: I've submitted an edit request for your question to change the tags to more accurately represent the content. The VSTO technology does not come into play. By using the MathType and Ms-Word tags the question may become visible to people who have some experience in this area and can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below C# code to highlight all MathType equation in yellow color.
Before using the this code add `using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;` in namespace declaration in your class file.

```
public bool FindAndHighlightMathtypeEquation(ref Word.Range myRange)
    {
        try
        {
            int inlineShapesCount = myRange.InlineShapes.Count;
            if (inlineShapesCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= inlineShapesCount; i++)
                {
                    Word.InlineShape currentShape = myRange.InlineShapes[i];
                    Word.Range currentShapeRange = currentShape.Range;
                    Word.WdInlineShapeType typeOfCurrentShape = currentShape.Type;

                    if (typeOfCurrentShape != Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!currentShape.Field.Code.Text.Trim().ToLower().Contains("equation"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    currentShapeRange.Select();
                    currentShapeRange.Application.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdYellow;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Process Completed");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Its really helpful for me.Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to highlight all fields in Word. Go to Word options, advanced, then under Show document content, choose "always" in the "field shading" option.
A shame it's in grey and not yellow, but very useful all the same.

Comment: At least in Word for Mac 16.27, this doesn't appear to apply to equations. The only "Field Shading" option available is in "Word Preferences" dialog > "Authoring and Proofing Tools" section > "View" dialog > "Show in Document" section, and it appears to apply only to mail merge fields, since the option indented right below the "☑ Mail merge prompts" option.

Comment: Also, the question asked for a way using c#.